# Threading Issue while database bulk insert?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 25 threads running. And each thread does following:

1. reads a txt file with around 1000 records,
2. put into datatable
3. sql bulkinsert into sql server

After starting all the threads, I need to wait for the threads to complete processing and for this I have used `Thread.Join`. My issue is, the threads finishes completion task even before they have finished with the above steps. Only reason I can see here is that, the database table gradually increases size to more that 20 million records. And there on, it takes some time to insert data. Is it that the thread gets aborted while waiting to insert data to SQL Server? I have even tried using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `ContinueWhenAll`, but result is same. Is there any better way of handling this?

Comment: Can you share a piece of source code?

Comment: We need some code, no one here is a mind reader (i think)

Comment: @Woot4Moo If you knew about any mind readers here, you'd be one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an exception is thrown inside some threads. Probably because of limitation of concurrent connections to database. You need to implement proper error handling and logging to understand the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.
1) If this task seems to complete before all threads have finished executing you are using synchronization incorrectly.
2) It is possible that your database runs out of available connections in its pool.  I believe by default most databases allow 10 concurrent connections.  (I am assuming you configured that properly).

CW as this is to long to be a comment.